# Reflection principle and independence results, externally and internally

Tags: set-theory

If I understand it correctly, for $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n$ any finite subset of ZFC, with the reflection principle and forcing, we can show, for example, that $\mathrm{ZFC} \vdash \mathrm{Con}(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n,\mathrm{\neg CH})$. It is quite convincing to conclude metamathematically that if $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is consistent, $\mathrm{ZFC} + \mathrm{\neg CH}$ is also consistent. But is it possible to show it internally, i.e. that $\mathrm{ZFC} \vdash \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC} + \mathrm{\neg CH})$? Can we obtain this result with a similar method ? My idea would be that, if we have $\mathrm{Con}(ZFC)$, we have a model $V'$, and we can construct, in this model, a model for any subset of $\mathrm{ZFC} + \neg \mathrm{CH}$, and by the compactness theorem, we can conclude $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC} + \neg \mathrm{CH})$. But we assume that if $V'$ thinks that some set is a model of a subset of $\mathrm{ZFC} + \neg \mathrm{CH}$, it is also true in the metatheory. Is it the case?

Comment: Yes. If ZFC has a model, it has a countable model, and then you can just force *directly* over that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If ZFC has a model, it has a countable model, and then you can just force *directly* over that model.

The whole point of using Reflection is that you can use a meta-theory as weak $\sf PRA$, and that you don't need to worry about forcing over non-transitive models.

Comment: So any construction that I do in a transitive countable model, I could also do it on a countable model in general? Because otherwise I can't see how to conclude.

Comment: Yes, you can force over arbitrary countable models. It can just gets... messy.

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau Elaborating on Asaf's comment, the primary issue is how to make sense of evaluations of names: if $M$ is ill-founded, what is $M[G]$ exactly? Of course in the well-founded case this is easy since we can just perform a genuine definition-by-recursion. However, if $M$ is ill-founded and $\nu$ is an ill-founded $\mathbb{P}$-name in $M$, it's not immediately clear how to make sense of $\nu[G]$ for $G$ $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$. The solution is to show that the necessary recursion can in fact be performed internally in an appropriate sense; this isn't trivial since $G\not\in M$.

Comment: The key tool unsurprisingly is the internal definition of the forcing relation itself, which - although motivated by well-foundedness - makes sense in any model. So this is a very nice exercise in the power of internal definitions: they let us extend subtle concepts to "bad" structures. (A secondary issue is the verification of Regularity in $M[G]$, which in the well-founded case is trivial. But this is solved in exactly the same way, so it's not really worth thinking about too much.)